# File Access in python

Tags: python

Whenever I go to load a text file for my program it displays the info in the text file yet when I input the roster function it does not display the text file and show it is available to be modified. Is it something with how I created the text file in the first place or is my coding for `loadData` not written correctly i think i may be confused on the difference between just setting up a function just to read back the file instead of actually opening the text file to be able to modify it.

```
dict_member = {}
players = dict_member
class Players:
    def __init__(self, name, number, jersey):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.jersey = jersey
    def display(self):
        print('Printing current members\n')
        for number, player in dict_member.items():
            print(player.name + ', ' + player.number + ', ' + player.jersey)
    def add(self):
        nam = input("Enter Player Name\n ")
        numb = input("Enter Player Number\n ")
        jers = input("Enter Jersey Number\n ")
        dict_member[nam] = Players(nam, numb, jers)
    def remove(self, name):
        if name in dict_member:
            del dict_member[name]
    def edit(self, name):
        if name in dict_member:
            nam = input("Enter Different Name\n")
            num = input("Enter New Number\n ")
            jers = input("Enter New Jersey Number\n ")
            del dict_member[name]
            dict_member[name] = Players(nam, num, jers)
        else:
            print("No such player exists")

    def saveData(self):
        roster = input("Filename to save: ")
        print("Saving data...")
        with open(roster, "r+") as rstr:
            for number, player in dict_member.items():
                rstr.write(player.name + ', ' + player.number + ', ' + player.jersey)
            print("Data saved.")
            rstr.close()

    def loadData(self):
        dict_member = {}
        roster = input("Filename to load: ")
        file = open(roster, "r")
        while True:
            inLine = file.readline()
            if not inLine:
                'break'
            inLine = inLine[:-1]
            name, number, jersey = inLine.split(",")
            dict_member[name] = (name, number, jersey)
        print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
        file.close()
        return dict_member

def display_menu():
    print("")
    print("1. Roster ")
    print("2. Add")
    print("3. Remove ")
    print("4. Edit ")
    print("5. Save")
    print("6. Load")
    print("9. Exit ")
    print("")
    return int(input("Selection> "))
print("Welcome to the Team Manager")
player_instance = Players(None, None, None)
menu_item = display_menu()
while menu_item != 9:
    if menu_item == 1:
        player_instance.display()
    elif menu_item == 2:
        player_instance.add()
    elif menu_item == 3:
        m = input("Enter Player to Remove\n")
        player_instance.remove(m)
    elif menu_item == 4:
        m = input("Enter Player to Edit\n")
        player_instance.edit(m)
    elif menu_item == 5:
        player_instance.saveData()
    elif menu_item == 6:
        player_instance.loadData()
    menu_item = display_menu()
print("Exiting Program...")
```

Comment: You shouldn't make substantial edits to your code, and change what you are asking. It invalidates all of the answers that pertain to the original code, making this whole question and answer group difficult or impossible to understand.

Comment: I can see the original question in the revision history.

Comment: A different error means people will be trying to solve a different problem. So you'll end up with some answers that have no relevance to the current question. That's not how this site is supposed to work.

Comment: My apologies @BryanOakley Just been pulling my hair out trying to learn python.

Answer (score -1):

you didnt load your data into `dict_member` before displaying the roster

when you load your data in the loadData function you redefine `dict_member`
so it will "shadow" the outer `dict_member` so when the `display` function is called `dict_member` will always be empty

so you probably want to remove this line

```
def loadData(self):
    #  **remove this line --->** dict_member = {}
    roster = input("Filename to load: ")
    file = open(roster, "r")
    while True:
        inLine = file.readline()
        if not inLine:
            break
        inLine = inLine[:-1]
        name, number, jersey = inLine.split(",")
        dict_member[name] = (name, number, jersey)
    print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
    file.close()
    return dict_member
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/Week5/Team Management 2.py", line 77, in <module>
    player_instance.loadData()
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/Week5/Team Management 2.py", line 44, in loadData
    name, number, jersey = (line.rstrip()).split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`

Comment: it seems that your file contains a line that doesnt have two `,` . perhaps a empty line? also notice you are removing the last character from the line when you do `inLine = inLine[:-1]

Comment: `,` in the text file? I tried changing the format inside the text file and it still would not load it into the program

Comment: ok after making the suggested edits I am now face with `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` How is that possible if my understanding is correct `file = open(roster, "r")` opens the file in `loadData`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def loadData(self):
        file = open(input("Filename to load: "), "r")
        text = file.read()
        file.close()
        for line in text:
            name, number, jersey = (line.rstrip()).split(',')
            dict_member[name] = (name, number, jersey)
        print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
        return dict_member

def saveData(self, dict_member):
        file = open(input("Filename to save: "), "a")
        for number, player in dict_member.items():
            rstr.write(player.name + ', ' + player.number + ', ' + player.jersey)
        print("Data saved.")
        file.close()
```

What I think was the error was you using `"break"` in string from instead of the command, `break` (no quotes required). I optimized the code a little so maybe it will work now? If not, what exactly happens? Try debugging as well as checking your file.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/Week5/Team Management 2.py", line 77, in <module>
    player_instance.loadData()
  File "C:/Users/Family/PycharmProjects/Week5/Team Management 2.py", line 44, in loadData
    name, number, jersey = (line.rstrip()).split(',')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`

Comment: @JasonRay, check your file? What does it look like?

Comment: The text file saves it this way if thats what your looking for Joe, 1234567890, 12Jack, 9876543210, 13